# Disable movie15 movies and U3D graphics for printing

Tags: pdftex, pdf, 3d

I am using the `movie15` package to include movies and U3D graphics into my document. I have it setup so that a PDF reader not supporting U3D will display a static image which I have chosen instead.

However, when printing the document, Acrobat Reader will print the U3D graphics instead of the static images. While this does not look terrible, I'd rather have it print the static images. How can I achieve this?

EDIT: Some code was requested.

```
\includemovie[
poster,
text={\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{fig/cross_curv}},
toolbar, 
label=cross_curv,
3Drender=SolidWireframe,
3Daac=30.000000, 
3Droll=0.000000, 
3Dc2c=-8.000000 -15.709999 -8.000000, 
3Droo=37.459366, 
3Dcoo=-8.000000 8.000000 8.000000,
3Dlights=CAD,
]{0.5\linewidth}{0.4890\linewidth}{figures/cross_curv.u3d}%
```

If the PDF reader does not support U3D, the file cross_curv.png will be displayed.

Comment: can you post a minimal?

Comment: I can post some code, but I am also interested in the general problem of sending different things to the screen and the printer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't make provision for that, sorry. You can disable printing by changing the value of the Annotation Flags (/F) in the generated PDF, or better, in movie15.sty [2009/07/07].

Lines 1120 & 1521: `/F 4` -> `/F 0`

Lines 1760 & 1920: `/F 5` -> `/F 1`

Alexander

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is an option: use another pdf reader to print the file.

Comment: I can of course solve the problem myself, using compilation options and, as you mention, another PDF reader. However, I would like the readers of my PDF to not have to worry bout this.